# How does @RequestScoped work in JSF?

Tags: jsf, scope

This bean controls editing a Player. When it's first loaded, it fetches a player from the database into the player property. The form displays fields correctly.

On submission, it seems that a player receives a new Player() object with values submitted on the form. Consequently, all player fields that are not on the submitted form are lost. One of those fields is player.playerId. Since the submission produces a player with null playerId, entity manager creates a new entity in the database.

I thought that request scope meant the PlayerEditBean will live and remember its state between GET and POST.

```
@Named
@RequestScoped
public class PlayerEditBean implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Inject
PlayerService playerService=null;

private Player player=null;

@PostConstruct
public void load() {
    String strId=FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequestParameterMap().get("id");

    // load entity if edit
    if(strId!=null) {
        Long id = Long.valueOf(strId);
        player=playerService.getPlayer(id);
    }
    if(player==null) {
        player=new Player();
    }
}

public void save() {
    playerService.savePlayer(player);   
}
```

Comment: Try changing the scope to @SessionScoped. Do you get any value in **strId** variable?

Comment: Ajeesh, `strId` only comes to play on initial form load. My question is about a subsequent `POST`. I don't know why you want to change scope to session. Every time a player is edited, it should result in new PlayerEditBean created. That to me is a request scope.

Comment: Your load() method will be called each time you request the server so it will result you with new player object.

Comment: @jacekn `@RequestScoped` means an instance of bean is created **for each single request** (doesn't matter if it's a GET or POST request). What you probably need here is `@ViewScoped`, which keeps the state of your managed bean till you don't return a navigation case from your action methods.

Comment: @ViewScoped does not exist in CDI. Looks like I'll have to retrieve the entity upon post and copy modified properties. This is stone age programming.

Comment: True, `@ViewScoped` doesn't exist in CDI. However, JSF 2.2 includes a CDI compatible annotation that you can use with your CDI managed beans. Also, Omnifaces library has a utility which you can use with CDI beans for versions prior to 2.2 also. [This link](http://wiki.omnifaces.googlecode.com/hg/javadoc/org/omnifaces/cdi/ViewScoped.html) will be useful to you. Just don't do copying properties, you have thousands of workarounds before that, event without `@ViewScoped`.